# Reshape data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape

I have a csv file which when read in pandas produces the dataframe in below format

```
  0             1                           2                    3                4                  5                6
 Day          Time                      2020-05-01 00:00  2020-05-02 00:00  2020-05-03 00:00  2020-05-04 00:00  2020-05-05 00:00
Night       23:00:00                            33            45                  33               23               19
Night       1900-01-01 00:00                    33            45                  33               23               19
Night       1900-01-01 01:00                    33            45                  33               23               19
Night       1900-01-01 02:00                    33            45                  33               23               19
Night       1900-01-01 03:00                    33            41                  23               23               19
Night       1900-01-01 04:00                    33            41                  23               23               19
```

Is there a way to convert the first row as a new column in the pandas that would output data as

```
 0            1                       2   3   4   5   6
Day          Time      Date          
Night       23:00   2020-05-01        33  45  33  23  19
Night       00:00   2020-05-02        33  45  33  23  19
Night       01:00   2020-05-03        33  45  33  23  19
Night       02:00   2020-05-04        33  45  33  23  19
Night       03:00   2020-05-05        33  41  23  23  19
Night       04:00   2020-05-06        33  41  23  23  19
```

Comment: What is code for `read_csv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is get columns names by second row:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[1])
```

Then split `Time` columns with `replace`:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.split().str[-1].str.replace(':00:00', ':00')
```

Add new column to 3rd position by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

```
df.insert(2, 'Date', pd.date_range(df.columns[2], periods=len(df)))
```

Set new columns names:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:3].tolist() + np.arange(3, len(df.columns)).tolist()
print (df)
     Day   Time       Date   3   4   5   6   7
0  Night  23:00 2020-05-01  33  45  33  23  19
1  Night  00:00 2020-05-02  33  45  33  23  19
2  Night  01:00 2020-05-03  33  45  33  23  19
3  Night  02:00 2020-05-04  33  45  33  23  19
4  Night  03:00 2020-05-05  33  41  23  23  19
5  Night  04:00 2020-05-06  33  41  23  23  19
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That helped me to reshape my data